# wordpress shows green screen in Germany

Tags: wordpress

Wordpress site http://sven-ratzke.com/ works when visited from The Netherlands.
Visited from Germany, the browser shows just a green colored page, no text, no images. The browser tab has this text: `<? echo $title; ?>`. So it seems PHP is not working when visited from Germany.

Why do people in germany see this:
https://electricbrain.eu/media/IMG-20180801-WA0000.jpg
and people from The Netherlands see a normal WP-site.

Marco

Comment: I'm in Canada and I see green... I don't think your issue is location-based.